# Confusing words in a economy news report: alone, on top of, absent

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, logic

> The report also highlights the rapid growth of export financing from
>   three Asian competitors: Korea, Japan and China. These countries
>   provided significantly more export-credit support to their respective
>   domestic companies and industries than did the United States in 2013.
>
> In addition, the report underscores two trends: unregulated
>   competition is expanding and commercial banks have largely withdrawn
>   from pockets of the export-finance arena, including providing support
>   for small businesses. The United States faces more robust competition
>   from export-credit agencies offering terms that are not regulated by
>   the Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development (OECD),
>   which encourages global export competition based on free-market
>   principles and mutually agreed-upon standards. For example, Ex-Im Bank
>   support for all of its **$15 billion** in medium- and long-term
>   financing was regulated by the OECD Arrangement, but other OECD member
>   countries offered more than **$60 billion** **alone** of unregulated
>   export financing support (**on top of $83 billion** in export
>   financing governed by the OECD Arrangement).
>
> Nations that are not subject to the OECD framework, including Brazil,
>   Russia, India and China, provided $115 billion in trade-related
>   financing. Unregulated support totaled substantially more than all
>   OECD-regulated support, a trend the report expects to continue and one
>   which is poised to place U.S. exporters at a competitive disadvantage
>   **absent** the tools made available by Ex-Im Bank.
>
> -- Export-Import Bank Report to Congress: Aggressive, Unregulated Financing from Foreign Competitors is Costing U.S. Jobs [Source](http://www.exim.gov/news/export-import-bank-report-congress-aggressive-unregulated-financing-foreign-competitors-costing)

Does **alone** modify **$60 billion**? And according to the bracketed sentence, **$60 billion** is on top of **$83 billion**? I think I misunderstand it, but I'm quite confused by these inconsistent numbers.

In addition, **absent** seems to be acting as a preposition here. If not, I think it should be **absent from**. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, Ex-Im Bank is a US-based financial institution regulated by the OECD. It offers $15 billion of export financing, which is part of the $83 billion total export financing governed by the OECD Arrangement.

So to answer your questions:

> And according to the bracketed sentence, $60 billion is **on top of** $83 billion?

Yes, this is correct. The OECD Arrangement is governing $83 billion of export financing, and the other OECD countries besides the US are offering an additional $60 billion *on top of* that.

> Does **alone** modify $60 billion?

I'd say no. It actually modifies the "other OECD member countries". They are offering the additional export financing independent of the US. They are offering the financing themselves--*alone*.

> In addition, **absent** seems to be acting as a preposition here. If not, I think it should be **absent from**. Is it a typo?

It's not a typo. It's taking the place of the phrase 'since they don't have' or 'if they don't receive' or 'without' something like that. But yes, it is functioning as [preposition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/absent?searchDictCode=all) here.

Comment: Google "absent define". I'm sorry the link doesn't work, but the search will.

Comment: That's OK; DT corrected it for you. I consulted OALD and Macmillan but couldn't find this particular entry. Thx!

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/absent#2-1    --     http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/absent  --  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/absent   -- http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/454886?uid=3738392&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21104825350531

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/absent_14  --  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/absent

Comment: This is a US usage; I just checked the BrE links. That's why I got nothing.

Comment: And while I was on my definition binge, I saw a note that it comes from legal jargon, so that would make it even harder to find in a BrE dictionary.

Comment: The default search engines are for BrE; I don't switch them very often.

Comment: Come to think of it, are you using "the other OECD countries **besides** the US" to actually mean "the other OECD countries **except** the US"? Are they identical here?

Comment: Yes, "besides" also means "except". "Beside" means "next to". At least, that's AmE uses them.